# Getting outOfmemoryError:Java Heap Space while generating chceksum on 2GB zip file

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have a code to generate the checksum and when i am trying to generate the checksum on a 2GB zip file , i am getting the outOf Memory error : Java heap space

```
2019-09-09:[TIME]10:31:53 ERROR Unhandled exception from message handler method
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unexpected handler method invocation error; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:569)
        at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:503)
        at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:93)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:505)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:439)
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:144)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have shown the code below for the Checksum - the stacktrace is pointing to the line

```
md.update(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(sourceFile)));
```

I have tried adding more heap space and run the application again but still getting the same error with huge file. with a small file there are no issues.

```
public static String getCheckSum(String sourceFile)
     {

  String checksum = null;
   try
   {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(sourceFile)));
    byte[] digest = md.digest();
    checksum = DatatypeConverter
      .printHexBinary(digest).toUpperCase();
    logger.debug("checksum value " +checksum);
    logger.debug("file " +sourceFile);
   }
   catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex)
   {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       logger.error(ex.getMessage());
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
     logger.error(e.getMessage());

   }
   catch (Exception exe)
   {
       exe.printStackTrace();
         logger.error(exe.getMessage()); 
   }
    return checksum;
}
```

Comment: Kinda obvious: you are trying to load the whole file into memory (`Files#readAllBytes`) and don't have enough memory.

Comment: `MessageDigest` is built so that you can easily pass it chunks of the file, one after the other. Loading the whole file into memory up-front is wasteful. Instead load chunks of it (using a `FileInputStream` for example) into a buffer (let's say about 8k bytes) and then pass that to `md.update()`.

Comment: Check how to do it properly, as @JoachimSauer says use MessageDigest, take a look into this site https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-generate-a-file-checksum-value-in-java/

Comment: thanks .. i will make the changes based on above link and try it out